# oracle join columns within a workload

Tags: oracle, join, workload

Is there a way to get the columns which participated in a join operation given a workload capture which has all the sql's within a time period? For example if I ran the following sql as part of the worload:

```
 SELECT * FROM HR.EMP A, OR.DEPT B where A.DeptID = B.DeptID;
```

I need to extract the following pair:

```
   <HR, EMP, DEPTID>, <OE, DEPT, DEPTID>
```

Is there a way to get this in oracle ? I am looking for any meta-data/dictionary  views which store this kind of information about join columns

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for but this is my try SELECT A.DEPT, B.DEPTID FROM HR.EMP A, OR.DEPT B where A.DeptID = B.DeptID;

Comment: No, I am looking for any meta-data views which store the usage of join columns in queries.

Comment: select * from user_views; to get information about views. I don't think there is any specific table/view which stores information about joins between tables.